Prometheus changes() function not working on [[processors.enum]] [[processors.enum.mapping]] value
I have Telegraf running for telemetry streaming via GRPC, with the following telegraf.conf configuration:
`[agent]
  logtarget = "file"
  logfile = "/var/log/telegraf/telegraf-core.log"
  debug = true
  quiet = true
  round_interval = false
  metric_batch_size = 1000000
  metric_buffer_limit = 1000000

[[inputs.jti_openconfig_telemetry]]
  servers = ["x.x.x.x:50051","x.x.x.x:50051"]

  sample_frequency = "5000ms"
  username = "xxxx"
  password = "xxxx"
  client_id = "Telegraf"

  sensors = [
    "interfaces_oper_state /interfaces/interface/state/oper-status"
  ]`

The database I'm using is Prometheus, with the following configuration:
`[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
  listen = ":9200"`

This setup results in the following enumeration response:
interfaces_oper_state__component_id{device="x.x.x.x", host="grafana-poc", instance="x.x.x.x:9200", interfaces_interface__name="name", interfaces_interface_state_oper_status="UP", job="job", location="example", path="sensor_1011:/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status/:/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status/:mib2d", system_id="example"} 65535. 
I want to create an alert based on the interfaces_interface_state_oper_status. To achieve this, I am using the [[processors.enum]] processor with the following configuration:
`[[processors.enum]]
  [[processors.enum.mapping]]
    field = "/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status"
    dest = "status_code"
    [processors.enum.mapping.value_mappings]
      "UP" = 0
      "DOWN" = 1
      "TESTING" = 2
      "UNKNOWN" = 3
      "DORMANT" = 4
      "NOT_PRESENT" = 5
      "LOWER_LAYER_DOWN" = 6`

This results in the following metric:
interfaces_oper_state_status_code{device="x.x.x.x", host="grafana-poc", instance="x:9200", interfaces_interface__name="name", interfaces_interface_state_oper_status="UP", job="Job", location="location", path="sensor_1011:/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status/:/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status/:mib2d", system_id="example"} 0. 
This configuration works as expected; when I create a visualization in Grafana and shut down an interface, the value changes from 0 to 1.
However, when I try to create an alert based on this metric using the changes(interfaces_oper_state_status_code[$__interval]) function, I always get a value of 0 (I tested it with all interval values), even when I shut down or bring up an interface.
Although the value of interfaces_oper_state_status_code changes, the changes() function does not seem to work as intended. It looks like the changes function gets multiple values (one for up, and one for down), so the changes function will never increase:
query = changes(interfaces_oper_state_status_code{device="1.2.3.4", interfaces_interface__name="xe-1/0/0"}[48h])

result = 
{device="1.2.3.4", device_type="xx", host="xxxx", instance="x.x.x.x:9200", interfaces_interface__name="xe-1/0/0", interfaces_interface_state_oper_status="DOWN", job="xxx", location="example", path="sensor_1005:/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status/:/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status/:mib2d", system_id="xxxx"}
0
{device="1.2.3.4", device_type="xx", host="xxxx", instance="x.x.x.x:9200", interfaces_interface__name="xe-1/0/0", interfaces_interface_state_oper_status="UP", job="xxx", location="example", path="sensor_1005:/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status/:/interfaces/interface/state/oper-status/:mib2d", system_id="xxx"}
0

I have tried other functions, like rate, delta, increase.
Since interfaces_oper_state_status_code changes in the right way when I bring up or shut down an interface, I am expecting that the result of changes(interfaces_oper_state_status_code[$__interval] would also work.
